# how to uninstall packages built from source and remove them entirely?

Tags: package-management, compiling, uninstall, libraries, source

I have built a lib, Open3D, from source and installed it. Afterwards, i ran make uninstall for the library and deleted the entire file directory which i cloned from git, i still have existing files from Open3D from /usr/local/lib directory. This is frustrating. How do i completely remove all these files? I don't face such problems if the package i require can be installed from apt.

This is what i get using

> ncdu

```
--- /usr/local/lib -------------------------------------------------------------
                         /..                                                    
  661.8 MiB [##########]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_mkl_mkl_merged.a
  661.8 MiB [##########]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_faiss_mkl_merged.a
  421.2 MiB [######    ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_embree_embree_avx.a
  411.7 MiB [######    ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_embree_embree3.a
  394.8 MiB [#####     ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_embree_embree_avx2.a
  311.7 MiB [####      ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_assimp_assimp.a
   93.0 MiB [#         ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_ippicv_ippicv.a
   48.1 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_webrtc_webrtc.a
   41.3 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_faiss_faiss.a
   34.6 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_zeromq.a
    6.8 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_imgui.a
    6.5 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_tbb_tbb_static.a
    6.5 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_mkl_tbb_static.a
    6.5 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_faiss_tbb_static.a
    6.1 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a
    4.2 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_jsoncpp.a
    3.9 MiB [          ]  libOpen3D_3rdparty_jpeg.a
```

Comment: Simple `rm`'ing would be enough. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: "*I don't face such problems if the package i require can be installed from apt*" Agreed, that's exactly why folks migrated from in-house-compiling to pre-compiled-packages 25 years ago.

Comment: @user535733 correct me if I am wrong but, not every package can be obtained via pre compiled  packages right

Comment: @Iberico I think you misunderstood what I wrote. I merely congratulated you on your independent discovery of an axiom of software distribution.

Comment: @N0rbert is that all the files that are installed if I run make install or check install? I am just afraid there will still be residual files in a random directory like what I discovered via ncdu. Because I thought all the files were entirely removed after make uninstall and deleting the entire folder. I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Possible way to fix is to get the same version of Open3D again, compile it, install and then run uninstall script for it. Manual digging inside full filesystem is time-consuming and ineffective.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking around, i managed to solve my problem. If you can build packages without building from source, do it. If not, when building your package from source, you will eventually run into having to run

```
make install
```

Instead of that, run

```
check install
```

to create a .deb package which can be easily removed with your package manager software when you want to uninstall. Doing so removes all the related files and data